# How to publish oracle database?

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a `.net` website that I built, which is connected to the oracle database on my machine (`localhost`).

When I decide to publish my website , how am I supposed to upload my database? since it's not a single file like *MSSQL*.

**update I don't have a dedicated server, I am gonna pay for domain and upload the website files to the hosting provider, and then upload my db to where-ever my website can I access it. I don't have any access to any hosting machine.**

Comment: you're going to have to install Oracle server on your website server (probably, unless you have > 1 server avail). And then one alternative you have is to use data pump to get your data out, and then back in - you'd upload the data pump output files to your server, and then pump it back in.

Comment: Upload your database where?  To, presumably, the hosting provider?  Depending on what you are trying to do exactly and what sort of access you have on the hosting server's machine, potentially you want to do a schema-level export and import.  But that's going to depend on a lot of specifics.

Comment: i dont have a dedicated server, im gonna pay for domain and upload the website files to the hosting provider, and then upload my db to where-ever my website can i access it. i dont have any access to any hosting machine.

Comment: Presumably, whatever hosting provider you are uploading the files to will have instructions on how to send them an Oracle database.  It is possible that they would want an export file.  It is possible that they would want a series of .sql files.  It is possible that they would want something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the server that will host the database has Oracle RDBMS installed, what you should do is use the "exp" or "expdp" Oracle utilities to export/create a "dump" file which you can then send to the hosted server team, and they would then us "imp" or "impdp" to import the database.

Or, now this this might be controversial in these modern IDE times, you should have your databse schema scripted into build scripts to:

1. Create the schema containers (TABLESPACES)
2. Create the schema owner
3. Create the tables
4. Create indexes/PK/FK
5. Add privileges to any ROLES/USERS
6. Add PLSQL, trigger code
7. Add static/lookup data

I presume you do not need to load any transactiona/account/customer data if your source database is where you did your development/testing, just the static data.

Send the build scripts to the hosted server team for them to apply via sqlplus.

The exp/imp method will (without delving into details about exclude rules) take everything.